# Phpmyadmin keeps asking for password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

Good day mates, this morning i was going to start my xammp control panel and i noticed that MYSQL tried to start, stopping immediately. Then i searched on the net for solution and i worked on data/backup folder to restart it. I also changed mysql port to 3309. When i tried to log on phpmyadmin dashboard it keeps asking me for user and pwd even if i removed it from it from config.inc.php

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'HTTP';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3309';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying you dont know that password?

Comment: I know the password, i cannot enter withit. So i tried to reset it or changing it but with no results

Comment: the password is the MySql password, not a phpMyAdmin one. So you have to fix it using mysql shell not the phpMyAdmin tool.

Comment: Change this line to cookie and it will throw you a login page `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

Comment: I cannot access even with cookie interface.
It says: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I can enter with 'pma' user but i cannot see any db, maybe no privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be dealing with several problems here.

First, if your MySQL stops immediately after starting it, you'll never be able to connect through phpMyAdmin, so is your MySQL now running?

Second, if you've messed around with the MySQL data folder, you could have corrupted the database. MySQL generally uses all of those files working together, and restoring one file from backup without changing others could lead to orphaned databases that MySQL sees but won't let you use, or preventing you from logging in all together. So please tell us a bit more about what you've done there so we can better understand what's going on.

So next, phpMyAdmin passes along your user information to MySQL; the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` line is only used when you're using auth_type config as a way of hardcoding the username and password in to the configuration file. That authentication type doesn't ask you for a password when connecting, so it's useful in some homelabs or other settings where no one else would have access.

Are you able to connect using the command line client with your username and password?

Comment: Hello, i was unable, due to the several and massive changes i've done, to make it start again. So i had to reinstall all. Luckily backups were saved and no problem occurred. This is the 2nd time i have this problem, and the 2nd time i reinstall. I tried to reimport db from old data folder but mysql says table doesn't exist.